# How to add headers for CreateSession in robot framework HTTP requests library

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using the requests library in Robot framework provided at [this github link](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/blob/master/doc/RequestsLibrary.html). The documentation implies that if can send custom headers by doing `CreateSession   <url> headers={'header1':'value1'} ....`
However, when I do that I get an error *"ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"*

This works

```
CreateSession SendCustomHeader http://myhost.com  verify=False
```

This does not

`CreateSession SendCustomHeader http://myhost.com  headers={'header1':'value1'}   verify=False`

I tried with various combinations of headers='header1' OR {'header1':'value1'}  OR 'header1':'value1' with same error

There does not seem to be an error in the requests library code RequestsKeywords.py

```
"        self.builtin.log('Creating session: %s' % alias, 'DEBUG')
        s = session = requests.Session()
        s.headers.update(headers)
"
```

I am not sure where the error is coming from and am therefore unable to fix

Any pointers to troubleshoot are appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't passing a dictionary, you're passing a string that looks like a dictionary. The solution is to create a proper dictionary and pass that in. Robot has a [Create Dictionary](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/Collections.html?r=2.8.4#Create%20Dictionary) keyword for this purpose.

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Collections

*** Test Cases ***
| Example
| | ${headers}= | Create dictionary
| | ... | header1 | value1
| | ... | header2 | value2
| | CreateSession | SendCustomHeader | http://myhost.com  
| | ... | header=${headers} | verify=False
```

Comment: excellent. I could have never guessed this one. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -5):

According to the [Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects), you may add headers to the Session object as:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('user', 'pass')
s.headers.update({'x-test': 'true'})
```

Comment: The OP isn't using the requests python library, they are using robot framework, which adds an abstraction layer on top of the requests library.